# python plot distribution across mean

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, plot

I have 500 simulation for each day in 2015. So, my data looks as:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2015', "%m/%d/%Y")
d2 = datetime.strptime('12/31/2015', "%m/%d/%Y")

AllDays = []
while(d1<=d2):
    AllDays.append(d1)
    d1 = d1 + td(days=1)
```

For each day I have 500 points representing temperature for that day.

```
TempSims.shape
(500,365)
```

I want to have a 2D plot with x-axis as dates and y-axis with a line showing mean of simulation for each day in 2015 and the 500 sims spread across the mean to show how mean stacks up against the distribution.

This is my first plot in python so I am having a hard time implementing it.

Edit:
My arrays are numpy arrays and date is datetime.

Edit2:
I am looking for plot as in this example:
[image]

Comment: are you using pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andy Hayden already suggested, pandas could be a very good option here:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2015', "%m/%d/%Y")
d2 = datetime.strptime('12/31/2015', "%m/%d/%Y")

AllDays = []
while(d1<=d2):
    AllDays.append(d1)
    d1 = d1 + td(days=1)

temps = np.random.normal( 20, 0.5, size=(500,365) )
temps = pd.DataFrame( temps.T, index=AllDays )

fig, ax = plt.subplots( 1, 1, figsize=(16,8) )
ax.plot( temps.index, temps.T.mean(), color='blue', linewidth=2 )
```

**Edit:**

Added the next line to plot the area you put in the example. Notice that for each x-value, you plot *only* 3 y-values: max, min & mean. Or whatever, you may of course want to plot the Q1 & Q3, or confidence intervals. My point is that you don't actually need the 500 points anymore (summary statistics are so great ^_^)

```
ax.fill_between( temps.index, y1=temps.T.max(), y2=temps.T.min(), color='gray', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_ylabel('temperature [°C]')
ax.set_xlabel('measuring date')
ax.set_ylim([15,25])

plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

[image]

**Note:** 
As already shown, you don't really need pandas for this, but it still great for a number of things and you may want to give it a try ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two already good posts above, but here is a pandas example.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("ggplot")

import pandas as pd


cols = pd.date_range(start = '2015-01-01', end = '2015-12-31')

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randn(500, 365), columns = cols)

means = df.mean()

ax = means.plot()

ax.set_title("means")

ax.set_xlabel('time')

ax.set_ylabel("averages")
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

using `matplotlib.pyplot` you can chart the mean, mean + 1 std, and mean - 1 std.

```
my_array = np.random.rand(500, len(AllDays))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(AllDays, my_array.mean(axis=0))
ax.plot(AllDays, my_array.mean(axis=0) + my_array.std(axis=0))
ax.plot(AllDays, my_array.mean(axis=0) - my_array.std(axis=0))
```

Looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can I plot all the points across the mean in a light color so that mean looks like a line in a shaded channel ? Each day has 500 points.

Answer (score 1):

I was fascinated by this question.  Here's what I came up with.  It's a work in progress.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2015', "%m/%d/%Y")
d2 = datetime.strptime('12/31/2015', "%m/%d/%Y")

AllDays = []
while(d1<=d2):
    AllDays.append(d1)
    d1 = d1 + td(days=1)

np.random.seed([3,1415])
my_array = np.random.randn(500, len(AllDays))

# Not an expert at using this yet... I'll learn.  But this works
y = np.mgrid[-2:2:201j, -2:2:365j][0]

# This transforms a y's into densities for the distribution described with data column.
# It assumes normal and in this case is true.
z = sp.stats.norm.pdf((y - my_array.mean(axis=0)) / my_array.std(axis=0))


# Copied from:
# http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/specialty_plots/advanced_hillshading.html
cmap = plt.cm.copper
ls = LightSource(315, 45)
rgb = ls.shade(z, cmap)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(rgb)

# Use a proxy artist for the colorbar...
im = ax.imshow(z, cmap=cmap)
im.remove()
fig.colorbar(im)

ax.set_title('Using a colorbar with a shaded plot', size='x-large')

plt.show()
```

Looks like:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your answers. I added a picture which shows what I was dreaming of.